# SQLite: Ошибка bindValue

Tags: php, sqlite3, bind

Товарищи! У меня странная ошибка (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on bool in…). Точнее, ошибка совсем не странная, но я не пойму, почему она возникает в моём случае. Есть запрос, который тупо не идёт дальше prepare, причём, аналогичный (полностью идентичный, за исключением того, что работает с другой таблицей) работает исправно. Вот код:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO feedbacks (email, content, dateAdded) VALUES (:email, :content, strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))";
$req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    var_dump($req);
$req->bindValue(':email', $feedback->getEmail(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue(':content', $feedback->getContent(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

var_dump($req) — bool(false). В чём может быть беда?

Comment: Очевидно, что надо получить код\текст ошибки, так как телепатов здесь мало. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.enableexceptions.php

Comment: Стыдно в этом признаться, но я писал в другую вообще БД. Т. е. я создавал таблицы в одной БД, которая в корне валяется, а путь в конфиге был к старой прописан. Надо больше спать, наверное